# diff two files in two windows

Tags: dired, diff-mode

After creating a split window and using dired in each, how do I run diff to compare two files?

I have looked but haven't found any clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you're asking.

But in Dired, provided you've loaded (e.g. `require`d) library `dired-aux.el`, you can use **`=`** (or menu **Immediate** > **Diff**), which runs command **`dired-diff`**, to diff the file listed on the current line against another file, for which you're prompted.

---

If you use library [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) ([`dired+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired%2b.el)), then `=` runs command **`diredp-ediff`** instead:

> **`=`** runs the command `diredp-ediff` (found in `dired-mode-map`), which is an
> interactive compiled Lisp function in [`dired+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired%2b.el).
>
> It is bound to `=`, `menu-bar immediate ediff`.
>
> `(diredp-ediff FILE2)`
>
> Compare file at cursor with file `FILE2` using `ediff`.
>
> `FILE2` defaults to the file at the cursor as well.  If you enter just a
> *directory* name for `FILE2`, then the file at the cursor is compared with
> a file of the same name in that directory.  `FILE2` is the second file
> given to `ediff`; the file at the cursor is the first.
>
> Try to guess a useful default value for `FILE2`, as follows:
>
> - If the mark is active, use the file at mark.
> - Else if the file at cursor is a autosave file or a backup file, use
>   the corresponding base file.
> - Else if there is any backup file for the file at point, use the
>   newest backup file for it.
> - Else use the file at point.